# host web application without purchasing domain name

Tags: .net, web-hosting

I've created a quartz (.net class) process that is been activated from the global.asax file, is it possible to purchase a suitable hosting package without a domain name (only ip) and then upload the cs and global.asax files in order to execute the proccess ?
thanks